# Can't update sas_ir_snmp package in CentOS 5.5

Tags: centos

I'm trying to get Intel's RAID Web Console 2 updated and working, and the sas_snmp and sas_ir_sanmp packages throw file conflicts at me, referring to a directory that seemingly doesn't exist. How can I force these to install/update, or fix the issue? And is the "lsi_mrdsnmp" a dependency?

Preparing...
                ########################################### [100%]
        file /etc/lsi_mrdsnmp/lsi_mrdsnmpagent from install of sas_ir_snmp-3.17-1111.i386 conflicts with file from package sas_snmp-3.17-1103.i386
        file /etc/lsi_mrdsnmp/lsi_mrdsnmpd.suse from install of sas_ir_snmp-3.17-1111.i386 conflicts with file from package sas_snmp-3.17-1103.i386
        file /etc/lsi_mrdsnmp/lsi_mrdsnmpmain from install of sas_ir_snmp-3.17-1111.i386 conflicts with file from package sas_snmp-3.17-1103.i386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (or rather shouldn't; there are ways to force it but both packages may fail if present) have both packages installed at the same time. Use `yum shell` to remove the first package before installing the second.

Comment: I can't have both sas_ir and sas_snmp installed? I'm trying to uninstall everything and start over, but I get this /etc/lsi_mrdsnmp/sas/uninstall: No such file or directory when trying to uninstall sas_snmp package...

Comment: Oh Intel... *facepalm*  You will need to prevent that package from running its uninstall scripts; see the man page for details (I refuse to give out information that could potentially fry a system in public channels).

Comment: lol facepalm!? I don't follow your concern, so bypass the uninstall scripts? Is there a different way to monitor my raid? Now you have me worried...